# Rails: File rout not correct (No route matches [GET] "/lot/log/folder/log.log")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I'm still trying to get the hang of ROR. My involvement has been minimal. Worked on fixing and expanding upon previously created applications. As a result I have some gaps in my knowledge that I believe also prevents me from the necessary vocabulary and technical recognition of information to search google/stack/etc for the appropriate answer. So bear with me here.

My issue is a simple one. I am currently iterating through a list of files, and populating an unordered list with links to download said files (.log files to be exact). Everything is displaying correctly, however the link itself is incorrect. So the issue being that if I click on the log1.log link it takes me to `http://blahblah.blah/lot/log/folder/log1.log` which presents me with the `Rails: File rout not correct (No route matches [GET] "/lot/log/folder/log1.log")` error . So I thought to myself, "let's just make sure the correct link takes me to where I need to go" and I changed the url in browser to http://blahblah.blah/log/folder/log1.log. Sure enough this didn't work either...there must be something I don't understand with how Rails works with directory structures.

So I am not getting the appropriate route...this must be simple, I'm losing sleep at night and my family life is falling apart (really it's only been a few hours). **How can I fix this?**

Here is the code for reference:

```
<h1>User Log</h1>

<div class="modal">
<!-- _results.html.erb loads here -->
</div>
<div class="form-container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <% Dir["log/*/*.log"].each do |file| %>
    <li><%= link_to file, file %></li>
    <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

The files are located in folders designated by month which are housed in the `log` folder.

so app/log/sept2013/log1.log, for example.

In summary - **What am I doing wrong and what don't I understand about routes? What solutions do I have and what are the common practices for accessing and displaying directories and files?**

Godspeed

Edit - as per request, routes.rb

```
App::Application.routes.draw do  

resources :alerts

# Users
devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'auth', :controllers => { :passwords =>     'users/passwords', :sessions => 'users/sessions' }
devise_scope :user do
get '/login' => 'users/sessions#new'
end
match '/users/me' => 'users#me'
resources :users

# Facilities
resources :facilities

# Lab Methods
resources :lab_methods

# Products
resources :products

# Qualities / Quality Control
match 'quality-assurance/modal' => 'quality#modal'
resources :qualities, :path => 'quality-assurance', :controller => 'quality'

# Quality History
resources :quality_histories, :path => 'quality-history', :controller => 'quality_histories'

# Lots
match 'lot/certificate_review' => 'lot#certificate_review'
match 'lot/:action', :controller => 'lot'
match 'lot/:action/:id', :controller => 'lot'

# Other
match 'dashboard' => 'main#dashboard'
match 'reporting' => 'main#reporting'
match 'settings' => 'main#settings'
match 'search' => 'main#search'
match 'search.xlsx' => 'main#search.xlsx'
match 'options' => 'main#options'

# Root
root :to => 'main#dashboard'

get "lot/user_log" 

end
```

Comment: Add your routes file to the question (routes.rb in the config subfolder), or you can do rake routes and it will tell you all the ones you've told it about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only access files that are in "public" folder directly. Here is what you can do though:

1. Create a new controller with an action to get logs.
2. Add route to this new action
3. Point your links to this route

The controller action might look like this:

```
class LogsController < ApplicationController
  def log
    send_file "log/#{params[:log_file]}"
  end
end
```

The route:

```
get "/log/:log_file", :to => 'logs#log', :constraints => {:log_file => /.*/}
```

Note the constraints option, it lets the log_file param to contain slashes

Comment: Okay, awesome thanks for the reply! I am starting to get a better idea. How then would I "point" my links to this route? Also, how will this change the look of my view code that I posted above?

Comment: Urls will be the same, for example ```http://blahblah.blah/log/folder/log1.log``` You just need to add / before the file path to get rid of the /lot part so: ```link_to file, "/#{file}"```

Comment: Got it, really straightforward actually! Thanks again!